# Errors with identifiers in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to run some PL/SQL code but it contains some errors about identifiers plese help me with it. The code is not running

```
DECLARE
   a := customer.purchase%TYPE;
   id := &employee.empno;
BEGIN
   UPDATE employee SET salary = salary + 5000;
   UPDATE employee SET bonus = bonus + 1000 WHERE empno = &id;
   SAVEPOINT sumeet;
   UPDATE customer SET purchase = purchase + 5000 WHERE custid = a;

   SELECT SUM(purchase) INTO a;

   IF (a < 11000) THEN
      ROLLBACK sumeet;
   END IF;
   COMMIT;

END;
/
```

Comment: What does "not running" mean, what errors are you getting? What did you intend to happen and what _is_ happening? Also, you have no cursors...

Comment: And the error is? Btw: shouldn't the commit be in an `ELSE` part?

Comment: declaration of id is wrong.

Comment: where are you set a value to `a`? `Select INTO` needs a `FROM`.

Comment: using a variable(`a`) for two things is a bad habbit.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Alen's fix, instead of the `ROLLBACK` why don't you do :

```
   UPDATE customer SET purchase = purchase + 5000 
    WHERE custid = a
      AND (select sum(purchase) from customer) + 5000 < 11000;

  COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1):

1: This is wrong:

```
DECLARE
  a := customer.purchase%TYPE;
  id := &employee.empno;
```

You don't put a `:=` after the variable name, `&` is invalid, and `employee.empno` is not a valid data type. i.e.:

```
DECLARE
  a customer.purchase%TYPE;
  id employee.empno%TYPE;
```

2: You don't need `&` to refer to the id variable:

```
UPDATE employee SET bonus = bonus + 1000 WHERE empno = &id;
```

i.e.:

```
UPDATE employee SET bonus = bonus + 1000 WHERE empno = id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this block, but first change the values (1, 2) in the declaration block.

```
DECLARE
   a customer.purchase%TYPE := 1;
   id employee.empno%TYPE := 2;
BEGIN
   UPDATE employee SET salary = salary + 5000;
   UPDATE employee SET bonus = bonus + 1000 WHERE empno = id;
   SAVEPOINT sumeet;
   UPDATE customer SET purchase = purchase + 5000 WHERE custid = a;

   SELECT SUM(purchase) INTO a FROM customer;

   IF (a < 11000) THEN
      ROLLBACK sumeet;
   END IF;
   COMMIT;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip: Combine your two updates on employee into one.

```
 UPDATE employee
 SET    salary = salary + 5000,
        bonus  = bonus  + case when empno = &id then 1000 else 0 end;
```

Also, start using meaningful variable names.